# WKWebView get the old value Scroll Height after rotate the phone iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, screen-rotation

I have the WKWebView inside a cell, but the problem is When rotated the phone, I get the old value of the WkWebView Scroll Height, For that reason the content don't load completly.

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.contentHeights[3] = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```

This method change the height of the row of the table cell but the value I get is before at to be rotated.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if indexPath.row == 3{
        return contentHeights[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        contentHeights[indexPath.row] = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        return contentHeights[indexPath.row]
    }


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 3{
        return contentHeights[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

The row 3 is the WkWebView Any Help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read several post after that I founded two way to resolve the problem.

**First I used KVO**

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "webView.scrollView.contentSize", options: .New, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
if keyPath == "webView.scrollView.contentSize" {
    if let nsSize = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSValue {
        let height = nsSize.CGSizeValue().height
        // Do something here using content height.
    }
}}

removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "webView.scrollView.contentSize", context: nil)
```

**The second way is a event on Javascript:**

Add the following code to html code:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$( document ).resize(function() {webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage($( document ).height())});});</script>
```

Add the WkWebView the following configuration:

```
var contentController:WKUserContentController!
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    contentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
        self,
        name: "callbackHandler"
    )

    config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), configuration: config)
}
```

Add the following function:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {  
    if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
        if !positionOrientationLanscape{
            sizeLanscape = CGFloat((message.body as! NSNumber).doubleValue)
            contentHeights[4] = sizeLanscape
        }else{
            sizePortrait = CGFloat((message.body as! NSNumber).doubleValue)
            contentHeights[4] = sizePortrait
        }
    }    
}
```

Don't forget deinit

```
deinit {   

        self.contentController.removeScriptMessageHandlerForName("callbackHandler")
    }
```